# Getting the attributes of a javascript variable from java

Tags: javascript, java

I create and instantiate an object in JS and passing it with a GET/POST request to a servlet, but it is recovering the attributes as null

I have tested to recover the values with an input stream but it shows them as empty.

```
<script>

       function Person(){

              this.name= ‘’;

              this.surname= ‘’;

       }

var agent = new Person();

agent.name = ‘Arya’;

agent.surname= ‘Stark’;

</script>
```

The agent variable will be passed to a GET/POST request.

I used to do it this way:

```
String nombre = request.getParameter("agent.name");

System.out.println(“name=” + name);
```

And this would be the expected console log:

`name=Arya`

But instead is recovering a null

If I print all the parameters:

```
Enumeration<String> parameterNames = request.getParameterNames();

       while (parameterNames.hasMoreElements()) {

             String paramName = parameterNames.nextElement();

System.out.println(“paramName=” + paramName);

       }
```

It shows:

```
paramName=agent
```

But not agent.name y agent.surname

If i try to recover the agent variable,

```
String agente = request.getParameter("agent");

System.out.println(“agent=” + agent);
```

It shows:

```
agent=[object]
```

Comment: um, how are you posting it to the server?

Comment: I don't see your HTTP post, which is where it matters.